# Did Maze War feature randomly generated mazes?

Tags: maze-war

I can't seem to find some basic information about [Maze War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_War).

Were the mazes randomly generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, Maze War. The first First Person Shooter. The version I played on the Mac network on college in 1987 did not have randomly generated mazes.